# SQL SERVER - UPDATE TOP with ORDER BY and hints: ROWLOCK, READPAST,XLOCK

Tags: sql-server, performance

Let's consider a table `[queue]` that represents a queue of items that should be processed by service. The main problem is that we have a few instances of service. Problems:

1. one item should be picked up only by one service.
2. we don't want to block other requests to this queue.
3. service should pick up the oldest item from the queue.

   ```
   update TOP(1) [queue] WITH (XLOCK, READPAST, ROWLOCK) 
   SET status = 2/*proccesing*/ 
   OUTPUT INSERTED.id
   where status = 1
   ```

It works, but only 1,2 goals are achieved. It's not allowed to use order by. How to add `ORDER BY`?

Comment: simply search the internet on "sql server use table as queue". Lots of examples - including [this one](https://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/) which demonstrates the same technique used by first answer.

Comment: @SMor I've noticed that in these examples XLOCK is not using. Could a deadlock happen in this case?

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious question - what happens if you put an `order by` clause on your update statement?

Comment: @BenThul An error. It's not allowed.

Comment: What error? I do `update top(x)` with an `order by` clause quite frequently. Either way, you're getting an error. What you could also do is run a `select` to get the PK  instead in the same transaction as the update and add `holdlock` to the table hints. Then you can do the update by PK.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15 Check here. There is no order by in syntax. Could you please share an example how you do this? It’s possible to rewrite query with cte or with sub query, but update and order by doesn’t work together

Comment: In the WideWorldImporters sample database on my local, I just did `update top(10) o set CustomerID = 832 output deleted.OrderID from Sales.Orders as o WITH (XLOCK, READPAST, ROWLOCK) where CustomerID <> 832` and no error was given.

Comment: You said that you could do it with ‘order by’

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
;With CTE as
(
    select Top 1 *  from [queue]  WITH (XLOCK, READPAST, ROWLOCK) order by YourColumnName
     --you can your own cond...and you can select Top number of rows..here i'm selecting only 1 row
)

Update CTE set status = 2
```